# getting value from button which is not in form

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets, button

Is it possible to get value from button which is not given in form...
for example..

```
<input type="submit" value="click here" name="subs" >
    <%
        if(request.getParameter("subs")!=null){
    %> <div> helo welcome</div><%
        }
    %>
```

Comment: Firstly,where do u want to get value:In page itselfor in ur controller class?Is there an existing form and u want button data to be submitted along with form.Please update ur question for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get value of a button using simple js.

```
<button id="buttonId" value="demo"></button>
<p id="pId"></p>
```

Then in your `js` file you can use

```
 var button  = document.getElementById("buttonId");
    var buttonValue = button.value();

            button.addEventListener("click", function(){

            document.getElementById("pId").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";

            //do something on click
        });
```

Comment: can I write "document.write('<p>heloo welcome</p>');" this inside the function ?? will it show me on the web page??

Comment: You can also use `appendChild` to append the elements dynamically, explore that also

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: (uses `JS` and/or `jQuery`)

```
var button_element = document.getElementById("ID_here");
button_value = button_element.value();

/* for this case, you might have to use: */
var button_value = button_element.attr('name');
/* use as intended */
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   In your code  what happens if the button is clicked??